# Control output format of do

Tags: r, dplyr

The following two `do` statements deliver slightly different results:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(30), y = rnorm(30), w = factor(sample(3, 30, TRUE)))

(r1 <- d %>% group_by(w) %>%
   do(data.frame(s1 = sum(.$x),
                 s2 = sum(.$y),
                 s3 = {
                    z <- seq_along(.$x)
                    sum(z)
                 })))
# Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
# Groups: w [3]
# 
#        w        s1         s2    s3
#   (fctr)     (dbl)      (dbl) (int)
# 1      1 0.1292572  0.8447634    45
# 2      2 0.2092895  3.3060157    91
# 3      3 2.1351984 -0.1675416    36

(r2 <- d %>% group_by(w) %>%
   do(s1 = sum(.$x),
      s2 = sum(.$y),
      s3 = {
         z <- seq_along(.$x)
         sum(z)
      }))
# Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
# Groups: <by row>
# 
#        w       s1       s2       s3
#   (fctr)    (chr)    (chr)    (chr)
# 1      1 <dbl[1]> <dbl[1]> <int[1]>
# 2      2 <dbl[1]> <dbl[1]> <int[1]>
# 3      3 <dbl[1]> <dbl[1]> <int[1]>
```

If I want now to add a more complex object to the output, I have to rely on the second form:

```
(r3 <- d %>% group_by(w) %>%
   do(s1 = lm(y ~ x, .),
      s2 = sum(.$y),
      s3 = {
         z <- seq_along(.$x)
         sum(z)
      }))
# Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
# Groups: <by row>
# 
#        w      s1       s2       s3
#   (fctr)   (chr)    (chr)    (chr)
# 1      1 <S3:lm> <dbl[1]> <int[1]>
# 2      2 <S3:lm> <dbl[1]> <int[1]>
# 3      3 <S3:lm> <dbl[1]> <int[1]>
```

So my question is, if there is an elegant way to combine the nice output of the unnamed form of `do` (in particular that vectors are stored as vectors and not as vectors of lists) with the ability to store also more complicated objects of the named version of `do`? Desired output would be something like this without the need of the extra `mutate`:

```
r3 %>% mutate(s2 = unlist(s2), s3 = unlist(s3))
# Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
# Groups: <by row>
# 
#        w      s1         s2    s3
#   (fctr)   (chr)      (dbl) (int)
# 1      1 <S3:lm>  0.8447634    45
# 2      2 <S3:lm>  3.3060157    91
# 3      3 <S3:lm> -0.1675416    36
```

**Edit**

This question is apparently not valid anymore, since in my current `dplyr` version I get `list` instead of  `chr`.

*Finally, why are `s1`, `s2` and `s3` in the second example of type `(chr)`?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the model in a `list`, and keep R from trying to unlist it with `I`.

```
r3 <- d %>% group_by(w) %>%
    do(data.frame(s1 = I(list(lm(y ~ x, .))),
                  s2 = sum(.$y),
                  s3 = {
                     z <- seq_along(.$x)
                     sum(z)
                  }))

#Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
#Groups: w [3]

#       w      s1         s2    s3
#  (fctr)   (chr)      (dbl) (int)
#1      1 <S3:lm>  0.8447634    45
#2      2 <S3:lm>  3.3060157    91
#3      3 <S3:lm> -0.1675416    36
```

(The printed type `chr` is a bug in `print.tbl_df`, since fixed in dplyr 0.5. Don't worry about it.)

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for. Cannot award the bounty before tomorrow.